# ¿como enlazo un html a mi index.html?

Tags: html5, css3

mi **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>



  </head>
  <body>
    <header>



    </header>
    <footer>



    </footer>


  </body>
</html>
```

El html que quiero enlazar **nav.html**, Esto es por que quiero utilizar mi navbar para varias paginas.

¿Hay alguna manera de enlazarlo para que se me visualice como si estuviera en el index?. No importa que haya en el nav pero quiero que se visualice.

Comment: para eso necesitas usar un framework ya sea backbone, angular etc

Comment: podrias darme un inicio por favor para guiarme, o sobre que busco en especifico para hacerlo.

Comment: <a href="index.html">

Comment: Me imagino que estas empezando, y que no quieres usar php ni un framework , echa un ojo a 'iframe'.

Comment: eso lo intente pero no me dejo poner la pantalla al 100%, me deja una margen.

Comment: La mejor solución para lo que quieres realizar es por medio de un Framework como node.js en donde puedes usar pug o jade armar tus plantillas e ir haciendo includes del codigo repetido en tu página o bien hacer un layout para solo cambiar el contenido.

Otra forma es usar React, Angular o Vue, te recomiendo el primero ya que posee una curva corta de aprendizaje comparado a los demás.

Comment: entonces me puedes decir que es lo que tengo que averiguar para empezar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te preparé un pequeño ejemplo que puedes ver aqui: http://embed.plnkr.co/ZLHMbNxEDq9TdeB2qDvE/

Utilicé JQuery y nada más:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <nav id="loadedNav"></nav>


    </header>
    <footer>



    </footer>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $.get( "nav.html", function( data ) {
      $( "#loadedNav" ).html( data );
    });
  });
</script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Básicamente, con la función `get`de `jQuery`puedes cargar vía `ajax`tu contenido html.

Answer (score -2):

Lo que yo haria seria convertir el `nav.html` a `nav.php`.
Ahora, en tu `index.html` agregar lo siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>



</head>
<body>
<header>

 <?php
 include("nav.php");
 ?>

</header>
<footer>



</footer>
```

Comment: ¿Y si no usa PHP?

Comment: esta e la única manera?